# Show that the only unbiased estimator for the zero-truncated Poisson distribution is absurd

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, estimation, parameter-estimation

Consider the zero-truncated Poisson distribution on the striclty positive integers, i.e.
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}_{\theta}(X=k) = \frac{\theta^k}{k!(e^{\theta}-1)}\,  \, \, , \, \, k=1, 2, ...
\end{align}
I show that the only unbiased estimator for $(1- e^{-\theta})$ is given by
\begin{align}
T(k) =0, \, \text{if $k$ is odd} \, \, \, \, \,\, \, \, \text{and} \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, T(k) = 2, \, \, \text{if $k$ is even}
\end{align}

I have to show that this estimator is absurd, but I don't see how to do it.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe absurd in the sense that your estimator is always either $0$ or $2$ whereas the parameter of interest is always positive.

Comment: Have been partially answered here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298139/unbiased-estimator-for-truncated-poisson/419250#419250